# How can I get the last page of results from API with no link headers?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the last page of results from an API, but the API does not seem to have any link headers.

Each page returns 100 results, so I need to loop through each page to get all the results, but without a rel"next" or rel"last" I don't know how to tell my script when to stop looping.

Is there another way to find out what the last page of results is from an API?

The API in question is [here](http://developer.leaddyno.com/rest-api.html).

Comment: Can you show the code for your current failing attempt? It helps to provide context.

Comment: Sorry, but I have already scrapped that code and moved on to trying to find another way.

Comment: The API you've mentioned seems to provide a count method. What about sending page = count / 100 ?

Comment: @HalilÖzgür I thought of that too, and it _should_ work, but if I get the count first, I then get a 401 unauthorized on subsequent requests, so it doesn't work. In other words it's either get the count or get the results, but not both.

Comment: This doesn't look normal. But if the API only allows a single request, how would you call the last page even if it was returned among the results?

Comment: See that's the thing I can get the results page by page no problem. But if I get a count first, then I can't get any results after that.

Comment: It's not normal I agree.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you provided, there is no way to know the number of pages. Perhaps, you can keep looping until you find an empty page, or a page with less than 100 results.